# how to redirect user to specific custom login page using OIDC Provider interactions

Tags: redirect, openid-connect, total.js, node-oidc-provider, oidc-provider

how to redirect  user to specific custom login page using OIDC Provider interactions

I am trying to implement oidc provider application. It working with the default autorisation Endpoint(login page) I first redirect to : http://localhost:8003/auth?client_id=oidcCLIENT&scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin%2Fcallback&state=BuAAA9hAF0IMTKpJQH51h9ueu8StadrmeNS9-cm_w3Q&code_challenge=mjEOrgT5j4CvQHd8ZJlmw7kh9COUpnxzgbLsBsPbIMA&code_challenge_method=S256

and after redirect to http://localhost:8003/interaction/4CvQHd8ZJlmw7kh9CO. Now I want to redirect user on a spécifique custom login page like http://localhost:8003/urlto/custom/autorisation_endpoin

please I need a help.

my configuration

start:
[image]

end:
[image]

my OIDC provider instance creation
[image]

listen:
[image]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following detail are my step to solve this problem

1. I create a new express project
2. I configure the created project
3. I follow [oidc provider using exemple](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/tree/9803ae73f53654bea311d63be08128e87a78ab76/example)
4. Now I have full access to oidc provider implementation